# should i convert uploaded photos into one format or keep their original format

Tags: php, image, image-processing, imagemagick

I'm writing a simple image upload function with php + image magick using amazon ec2 + s3.

The function basically receives the image, possibly compresses, and resizes it into 3~4 different sizes and the images get accessed more frequently than they are uploaded.

Not being an expert on digital images, I'm still deciding on whether to convert uploaded images into jpeg or keep their original format (jpeg, png, gif - gif will be converted into a still image in case the format gets converted).

There are two things to take into consideration that I can think of.

1. computing power usage (better not to convert)
2. network bandwidth (better to convert)

any recommendation?

Comment: If images are more frequently accessed than uploaded, why not convert to save the bandwidth?

Comment: given that they are being resized anyways, conversion may not save space in the first place.

Comment: FYI you don't only want to convert size, but also flatten images, convert to correct color space (yes, sometimes user upload CMYK etc) and remove (or keep) meta data. For example, for small thumbs we always strip meta (EXIF, etc) because sometimes it's larger than the image itself. But on large images we keep meta data, especially due to the fact that it may contain copyrights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you want to keep the original image. You might need it later if you decide to redesign site and change image formats globally. If you don't keep the original, you will not be able to re-process them in such situation.

Re. computing power usage -- you should not worry about that. You resize only once, and then optimized image size compensate on CPU and bandwidth later every time images are loaded.

Comment: good point. better to keep the original image. but do you think it's better to convert the image that is actually being displayed?

Comment: In production we convert them for display at preset sizes and quality, and we have about a dozen different sizes. And yes we had a situation when we needed ALL of the original images when we riesized main content area width from 600px to 780px. Then we used originals to create new main size.

Answer (score 0):

It's typically not a great idea to change the image format that a user uploaded. Certain formats have their own characteristics and benefits, and changing the format may not be ideal. For example, png has better support for transparency than gif or jpeg. So the conversion may cause your image to look odd.

Answer (score 0):

png and gif are better at compressing certain types of images, basically blocky graphics,  while jpeg are better for photo-like images.  So depending on the type of images your uploading there may not be a gain there in saving bandwidth/storage space.

The computation to convert will be expensive and it will slow down your web server if you aren't doing it asynchronously.

If your usage of the images can accept either type (jpg, png, gif)  than I would suggest keeping them in the format that it receives.